# Grok Filter Pattern for detecting multiple Unique Strings

Tags: regex, logstash, kibana, grok

I am currently trying to parse logs using a grok filter. Here is the Log Statement I am testing with:

`2023-03-07T19:09:26.661856688Z stdout F {"test1":"one","level":"info","message":"Query Params","requestId":"66x66x7b7951a5d9c609359146b3f435","test2":"two"}`

Here is my current Grok Pattern:

`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:[container][log][timestamp]} (?:%{WORD:[container][log][stream]}) (?:%{WORD:[container][log][designator]}) {(%{GREEDYDATA:data_before},)?("level":%{DATA:SEVERITY})?(,%{GREEDYDATA:data_after_severity},)?("requestId":%{DATA:requestId})?(,%{GREEDYDATA:data_after_id})}`

The goal of the grok pattern is to extract out 2 specific fields in the log body: level and requestId. The above pattern successfully extracts the requestId, but not the level. Result data seen below:

```
{
  "[container][log][timestamp]": "2023-03-07T19:09:26.661856688Z",
  "requestId": "\"66x66x7b7951a5d9c609359146b3f435\"",
  "[container][log][stream]": "stdout",
  "data_before": "\"test1\":\"one\",\"level\":\"info\",\"message\":\"Query Params\"",
  "[container][log][designator]": "F",
  "data_after_id": "\"test2\":\"two\""
}
```

How can I get the grok filter to also extract the level? I assume I have a syntax/formatting issue of some sort.

Comment: You moved the comma after `level` part to the `data_after_severity` group, try replacing `{DATA:SEVERITY})?(,%{GREEDYDATA:data_after_severity},)?` with `{DATA:SEVERITY},)?(%{GREEDYDATA:data_after_severity},)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the reply. That currently doesn't seem to change the output unfortunately. I've been stuck on this for a bit now

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `(%{GREEDYDATA:data_before},)?("level":%{DATA:SEVERITY})?` is that the second match has a ?, meaning zero or more times. The GREEDYDATA preceding it will consume the "level" and "message" items and the second match will occur zero times. You may be able to fix it by removing the ?.

Alternatively, match all of the JSON into a single field and parse it using a json filter.